# How to resolve something.something programmatically

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have following code:

```
;(function($){

    var getWeatherInfo = function(url, requiredKeys ) {

        var info = {},
            dfd = $.Deferred();

        $.getJSON( url, function( data ) {  
            for(var i = 0; i < requiredKeys.length; i++) {
                info[requiredKeys[i]] = data[requiredKeys[i]];
            }

            dfd.resolve(info);
        }); 

        return dfd.promise();
    };  

 var url = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk',
    requiredData = [
                    'name',
                    'coord.lat',
                    'coord.lon',
                    'description'
                  ]; 
 getWeatherInfo(url,requiredData).done(function(data){console.log(data)});
```

The data output is:

```
Object {name: "London", coord.lat: undefined, coord.lon: undefined, description: undefined}
```

`Name` is working fine because it doesn't have `.` How can I fix rest? I don't want to use eval. Is there any better alternative?

Comment: If you're not going to use `eval()`, you will need to break the string into it's pieces at the `.`  so you can reference each piece separately.

Comment: Remove `coord.` portion of string, or substitute `-` for `.` ?

Comment: @jfriend00 That makes is really messy. Can you thing of any alternative here?

Comment: @JS-JMS-WEB What makes what _"messy"_ ? What is purpose of `.` within string `'coord.lat'`, `'coord.lon'` ? What is expected result ?

Comment: The response is structured like this:
{"coord":{"lon":-0.13,"lat":51.51}}.
So you can access it with data['coord']['lat'] or data.coord.lat

Comment: @guest271314 it is a reference to appropriate API value. Just click the URL .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work:

```
$.getJSON( url, function( data ) {  
            for(var i = 0; i < requiredKeys.length; i++) {
                if (requiredKeys[i].indexOf('.') > -1){
                    var ar = requiredKeys[i].split("\.");
                    info[requiredKeys[i]] = data[ar[0]][ar[1]]
                }
                else{
                    info[requiredKeys[i]] = data[requiredKeys[i]];
                }
            }

            dfd.resolve(info);
        });
```

Result: Object {name: "London", coord.lat: 51.51, coord.lon: -0.13, description: undefined}

http://jsfiddle.net/gpzd9w43/

EDIT:

Maybe a more elegant way to do it if you have more than 1 dot:

```
    $.getJSON( url, function( data ) {  
        for(var i = 0; i < requiredKeys.length; i++) {
            var ar = requiredKeys[i].split("\.");
            var node = data;

            for (var j = 0; j < ar.length; j++){
                node = node[ar[j]];
            }

            info[requiredKeys[i]] = node;
        }

        dfd.resolve(info);
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gpzd9w43/1/